# sending mail Laravel 5.4 Godaddy hosting

Tags: laravel, smtp, laravel-5.4

I have hosted my application at [Godaddy](http://godaddy.com). I am trying to send out mail, but it's failing. I see the following error

> 1/1 Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268: Connection
>   could not be established with host localhost [ #0]

My `.env` configuration for mail is as follows

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp MAIL_HOST=localhost MAIL_PORT=25   
MAIL_USERNAME=support@mydomain
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXXX 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

SSL SMTP typically does not use port 25

Usually 587 or 465

Check your documentation from your SMTP host. (Or turn off SSL)